# Insert Multiple Rows under Active Cell using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, insert, rows

I'm writing a macro that runs through each row (some rows contain more columns of than others) and counts the number columns and inserts that same number as blank cells below the selected row. The goal is to eventually copy and paste the data to a single column.

I'm able to insert the correct number of blank cells, but they are inserted above the selected row. I would like for them to be inserted below the selected row. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
    rowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E" & rowCount).Select
    For c = 1 To rowCount
        columnCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, 
        Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 5
            If columnCount > 0 Then
                Let CopyRange = "E" & c & ":" & "E" & (c + columnCount - 1)
                ActiveSheet.Range(CopyRange).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        rowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        c = c + columnCount
    Next c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert 1 row below the one you are currently inserting. Also, you can simplify this by looping backwards.

```
rowCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
For c = rowCount to 1 step -1
    columnCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 5
        If columnCount > 0 Then
            Set CopyRange = "E" & c + 1 & ":" & "E" & (c + columnCount)
            ActiveSheet.Range(CopyRange).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
Next c
```

NB: This is untested